# How to retrieve an element from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to retrieve all elements from an ajax call, then insert them into another element without:

- using jquery (I just want to use pure JavaScript)
- creating a new element to contain the ajax response

Here's what I have tried:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function loadPage() {
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open('GET', 'test.php', true);
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){
                    if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){
                        document.getElementById('output').appendChild( ajax.responseText ) ; 
                    }  
                };
                ajax.send();
                }

                loadPage();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output">
            <h1>Default</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**test.php**

```
<h1>
     its work
</h1>

<div>
    <h2>
        its work2
    </h2>
</div>
```

I already googled it, but the answer was always to use jQuery.

Comment: Every element you create in javascript returns a reference to that node. But during ajax call there is no reference. So you can't use appendChild, instead of that use document.getElementById('output').innerHTML =  ajax.responseText  ;

Comment: i dont want to erase tag <h1>default</h1> inside that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node.appendChild` requires a `Node` object as an argument. What you're getting from test.php is a string. Try using `innerHTML` instead

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
```

As of XHR level 2, you can simply attach an `onload` handler to `XHR` instead of checking the `readyState` and `status` properties.

```
ajax.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += this.responseText;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to erase tag <h1>default</h1> inside that div

Comment: You can concatenate the existing `innerHTML` with the new content using `+=` . I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this

http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp

http://w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

I think the most of the examples that  you find use jquery because jquery makes it cross browser

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
   function loadPage(){ 
var strURL="test.php";

var req = getXMLHTTP();

if (req) {

req.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (req.readyState == 4) {
// only if "OK"
if (req.status == 200) { 
document.getElementById('output').value=req.responseText; 
    } else {
alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
}
} 
} 
req.open("POST", strURL, true);
req.send(null);
} 

}



 function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e1) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }
```